# How to dereferrence the array

Tags: perl

I am trying to retreive the the individual elements of the array stored as a reference.

```
my @list = ("three 13  3  1  91 3", "one   11  5  1  45 1",
            "two   12  7  1  33 2", "four  14  1  1  26 4");

my @refList = map { [$_, (split)[-1]] } @list;

# see what it is in @refList
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(@refList);

print "\n the value is $refList[0][0][1]";
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          'three 13  3  1  91 3',
          '3'
        ];
$VAR2 = [
          'one   11  5  1  45 1',
          '1'
        ];
$VAR3 = [
          'two   12  7  1  33 2',
          '2'
        ];
$VAR4 = [
          'four  14  1  1  26 4',
          '4'
        ];

 the value is
```

But i need the output of

```
 print "\n the value is $refList[0][0][1]" as 13
```

How to get the value

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
my @list = ( "three 13 3 1 91 3", "one 11 5 1 45 1", "two 12 7 1 33 2", "four 14 1 1 26 4" );

my @refList = map { my @t = split; shift(@t); [ $_, @t ]; } @list;

# see what it is in @refList
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(@refList);

print "\n the value is $refList[0][0][1]";
```

Comment: `my @refList = map { my(undef,@t) = split; [ $_, @t ] } @list;` would be slightly better.

Answer (score 6):

You are using one too many `[0]` in your print, to reference the value `3` you are talking about it should read

```
$refList[0][1]
```

---

I think I'm going mental, I swear I thought you were talking about the value `3` earlier.
Though I see no changes in your post, odd.. I blame the lack of sleep.

If you are looking for the value `13` (which your posts currently says) you should change your code to something as the below

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @list    = ("three 13 3 1 91 3", "one 11 5 1 45 1", "two 12 7 1 33 2", "four 14 1 1 26 4");
my @refList = map {@_=split;$_[0]=$_;[@_]} @list;

# print Dumper [@refList];

print "\n the value is ", $refList[0][1];
```

If you just want each string to be turned into an array reference, use this as the declaration/definition of `@refList`.

```
my @refList = map {[split]} @list;
```

Answer (score 3):

As refp said you're using too muck `[0]`, you could do:

```
my @list    = ("three 13 3 1 91 3", "one 11 5 1 45 1", 
               "two 12 7 1 33 2", "four 14 1 1 26 4");

my @refList = map {[split]} @list;
print "\n the value is ", $refList[0][1];
```

But if you want to have these 3 levels, this will do the job:

```
my @list    = ("three 13 3 1 91 3", "one 11 5 1 45 1",
               "two 12 7 1 33 2", "four 14 1 1 26 4");
my @refList = ([map {[split]} @list]);
print "\n the value is ", $refList[0][0][1];
```